# First time useState not showing up on UI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, onchange

My simplified code is below.

**Goal:** To display the names of the images that the user selects. The user selects an image, it is saved to a service, and I use a "put" request to get the images for that particular object, and then display the name. These steps are required for getting the names.

**Issue:** When I **first** select images via the "file upload button" (Form.Control), the image name(s) do not display on the #1 (commented as "#1: HERE!", at the bottom of code). When I go back and select more images, then #1 correctly displays the previously selected images AND the newly selected images (which is the correct behavior). My problem is that **on the first selection**, the image name is NOT being displayed.

```
const MyComponent = () => {

 const [fileNames, setFileNames] = useState({});

 // a service that calls gets the file names from objectId
 const getFileNames = (objectId) => {
   const input = { objectId: objectId };

   fetch(service(), {
       method: "PUT", 
       headers: {..(stuff here), "Content-Type": "application/json"},
       body: JSON.stringify(input)
    })
    .then( res => { res.json() })
    .then( resJson => {
       if( //resJson has errors) {
          //log error msg
       else {
          // problem is here????
          setFileNames(resJson.results);
          return resJson;
       }
     })
     .catch( err => //stuff here)
  }
  
 const handleFileChange = (e) => {
      // saves selected file(s) to particular objectId
      saveFile(event.target.files), props.objectId, props.somethingelse);
      getFileNames(props.objectID);
 }
    
 const showName = (file) => {
    return (
       <span> {file.name} </span>
    )
 }
    
 return (
     <div>
        <Form.Control 
            type="file" multiple
            onChange={ e=> {handleFileChange(e)} }
            {/* bunch of the stuff here */}
        />
        {/* ***********#1 - HERE!*************** */}
        {fileNames.map( file => file.showName(file) )}
     </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are not waiting for the file to be saved before you get the filename. That's why perhaps the first save is empty?

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [fileNames, setFileNames] = useState([]);
  // This should be an array be default since you map over it later down

  // make this an async function
  const getFileNames = async (objectId) => {
    const input = { objectId: objectId };

    let resJson;
    try {
      const result = await fetch(service(), {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(input),
      });
      resJson = await result.json();
    } catch (error) {
      // TODO: error handling
    }

    if (resJson.error) { // TODO: fix me
      //log error msg
    } else {
      setFileNames(resJson.results);
    }
  };

  // this too should be an asnyc function
  const handleFileChange = async (event) => {
    // I assume saveFile is an async function
    await saveFile(event.target.files, props.objectId, props.somethingelse);
    // save the file here ^ and wait for it to finish saving
    await getFileNames(props.objectID);
    // after you saved the file get the filename now
  };

  const showName = (file) => {
    return <span> {file.name} </span>;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form.Control
        type="file"
        multiple
        onChange={(e) => {
          handleFileChange(e);
        }}
      />
      {/* bunch of the stuff here */}
      {fileNames.map((file) => file.showName(file))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I appreciate your response. I am getting a message for the line "const resJson = await result.json()", saying that "resJson" is declared, but not read anywhere, even though I have edited the code to be exactly like yours. Any idea why?

Comment: Oops sorry I wrote this pretty quickly. Just edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. However, it is saying that resJson is undefined now, when previously, it was getting a successful response.

Comment: Did you make the change I made in my edit?

Comment: Yes, I added the "let resJson;" and removed the "const"

Comment: So where could it be `undefined`? Where are you getting that error?

Comment: BTW, I am new to "async"; hence these minor questions. I'll be looking into "async" more after I get this to work successfully.

Comment: The error is at the line: "setFileNames(resJson.results)". It says: "Unhandled rejection (TypeError): resJson is undefined."

Comment: Go into the `catch` block and add a `console.error(error);`. I assume the fetch fails and `resJson` is never set

Comment: Also I just added `if (resJson.error) {` but that's of course a guess. You have to do your own thing. You just had a comment in that place that would make the JS invalid. Fill that out with whatever condition you had for checking if the result is valid

Comment: BTW, in my original code, I moved the getFileNames from handleChange into the saveUploaded files, inside the second .then. And it worked. I appreciate all your suggestions.